# Is there a name for this shortest path algorithm?

Tags: tree, shortest-path

I have a matrix MxN of integers. I would like to calculate a shortest path through the matrix such that:

I start by taking any value from the first column.
I must then go to 1 number in each of the N columns in turn. 
I can only travel down and right. (I must travel downwards
 at least once for each move right)
for example if I have this matrix:

```
3, 2, 3
1, 5, 6
4, 8, 12
7, 8, 9
```

The shortest path would be 3, 5, 9 (going (0,0), (1, 1), (3, 2))

---

Another way to visualize it I suppose would be a tree where the children of the starting node would be (3, 1, 4, 7) (lets call these (i, 0))and each of those children has their own children being the following column from i+1.

e.g.
the first child of the starting node (3) would have children (5, 8, 8).
the second child (1) would have children (8, 8).
and so on.

### The algorithm is then the shortest path from the starting node to any of the leaves.

Bad explanation I know.

But does this algorithm have a name? Has anyone made it??

EDIT: For clarity this is the tree (excuse my paint skills.)
[tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7gewE.png)

Comment: It is unclear what you're trying to achieve with this

Comment: For clarity, consider adding the complete tree representation for your 4x3 matrix.

Comment: Ok added! I just want the shortest of all the paths to the Mth level of the tree.

Comment: You can not talk about shortest path to a level of a tree. Each path to the Mth level node would be a shortest path.